# Why insert data is not shown, only update data is show?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table.First table shows input data, second table shows output data and third is total table where we shows our product total balance.

```
1.input table
Date   | product_name | in_qty 
5/7/19 |     A        |  10    
5/7/19 |     B        |  15    
6/7/19 |     A        |  10   
6/7/19 |     C        |  20
```

```
2.output table 
Date   | product_name | out_qty 
7/7/19 |     A        |  10    
8/7/19 |     B        |  10
```

```
3.total balance table 
 product_name  | in_qty | out_qty | total_qty
     A         |  20    |  10     |   10      
     B         |  15    |  10     |   5
```

There my problem is in input table product C is not show in the total table. Which product add in the output table only those product total shown in the total table.

```
$res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT i.product_name, i.in_qty, o.product_name,o.out_qty
 FROM input i, output o
 WHERE i.product_name= o.product_name");

                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))    
                                    {

                                     $in_name = $row['product_name'];
                                     $inqty = $row['Input_qty'];;
                                     $out_name = $row['product_name'];
                                     $outqty = $row['Out_qty'];

                                     $sql=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO total (product_name,Input_qty,Out_qty) 
                                VALUES('$in_name','$inqty','$outqty')");

                                    $sql2=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE total t2
                                                INNER JOIN (
                                                  SELECT product_name, SUM(in_qty) as qty_total
                                                  FROM input
                                                  GROUP BY product_name
                                                ) t1 ON t2.product_name= t1.product_name
                                     SET t2.in_qty = t1.qty_total");
                                    }
```

My expectation is :

```
3.total balance table 
 product_name  | in_qty | out_qty | total_qty
     A         |  20    |  10     |   10      
     B         |  15    |  10     |   5  
     C         |   20   |         |  20
```

Answer (score 0):

your mysql query is wrong.

use following query .

```
SELECT columns  
FROM table1  
LEFT [OUTER] JOIN table2  
ON table1.column = table2.column;
```

in your case:

```
  SELECT input.product_name , input.in_qty , output.out_qty
  FROM input  
  LEFT [OUTER] JOIN output  
  ON input.column = output.column;
```

Comment: What if there's a product in the output table which is not present in the input table? I also think that MySQL will be unable to cope with `[OUTER]`.

Comment: i think without input product, output of that product is not possible.

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav Or you could read up on what a left outer join does. This is a good answer to your question. See: [MySQL LEFT JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

Comment: @kishanvekariya where i use your code. in the place of $res, $sql or $sql2?

Comment: @FazlulHoqueSawrav $res

Comment: @kishanvekariya its not work there shows an error ( mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in  )